# What can I do to avoid race conditions for multiple callbacks in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I have a dashboard very similar to this one-
import datetime

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# pip install pyorbital
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('live-update-graph', 'relayout'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(relayout, n):
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'relayout':
        * code that affects the y axis * 
        return fig 
    else:
        satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
        data = {
            'time': [],
            'Latitude': [],
            'Longitude': [],
            'Altitude': []
        }

        # Collect some data
        for i in range(180):
            time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
            lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
                time
            )
            data['Longitude'].append(lon)
            data['Latitude'].append(lat)
            data['Altitude'].append(alt)
            data['time'].append(time)

        # Create the graph with subplots
        fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
        fig['layout']['margin'] = {
            'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
        }
        fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

        fig.append_trace({
            'x': data['time'],
            'y': data['Altitude'],
            'name': 'Altitude',
            'mode': 'lines+markers',
            'type': 'scatter'
        }, 1, 1)
        fig.append_trace({
            'x': data['Longitude'],
            'y': data['Latitude'],
            'text': data['time'],
            'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
            'mode': 'lines+markers',
            'type': 'scatter'
        }, 2, 1)

        return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In my case, I have three different intputs. One input gets triggered by an dcc.interval timer, like in the example. Another input gets triggered when a user zooms in on the dashboard using the `Input('live-update-graph', 'relayoutData'` input and the last triggeres when a button gets pressed.

All three inputs are totally independent. One updates the data stored in `fig['data']`, another updates the data stored in `fig['layout']['xaxis']` and the last updates the stuff in `fig['layout']['yaxis']`.

I am concerned about the this situation:

- The dcc interval input gets triggered and the function starts to update the data
- The user zooms in on the dashboard and triggers the relayout data
- The dcc.interval returns a figure

Now, because the relayout input got triggered second, it has stale data. There is a race condition and it is possible that the dcc interval gets undone as a result.

What can I do to avoid the race condition? I wonder if it's possible to update only a part of the figure with a callback rather than editing the whole object.

Comment: Why don't you just make it one callback triggered by the interval and update all the outputs that need to be synchronised in that callback?

Comment: That doesn't quite solve it because they can still have a race condition. For example, let's say it takes the callback that updates the data 200 ms to complete and it takes 50 ms to relayout the data. Even if they are in one callback, it's possible that a user tries to relayout the data and stops the update or vice versa

Comment: In other words, because plotly over-writes an existing callback when a new callback gets fired, it seems like it is stuck in this race condition scenario

Comment: Where is Input('live-update-graph', 'relayoutData') in your code ?

Comment: If you are convinced you can't factor out the race condition, then some options appear to be (in no order): 1) to very carefully introduce a mutex bound to that user sessions, 2) force the callbacks that could race to be sequential by making one use an input dependent on the other's output (even if that's a dummy element like an empty dcc.Store).

Comment: "_because plotly over-writes an existing callback when a new callback gets fired, it seems like it is stuck in this race condition scenario_" Do you have a reproducible example ?

Comment: Sure, I added an example. The callback never finishes because it over-writes the in progress callback every time the interval component fires

Comment: I meant a _reproducible_ example of the scenario you described. The added snippet just adds confusion, I still don't see `Input('live-update-graph', 'relayoutData')`,  you were talking about 3 callbacks, there are only 2 in the code above.

Comment: @Cauder your example isn't reproducible because if we copy and paste it, it won't run. can you provide an example of the race condition you described that we can run locally? I want to help, but I would need to reproduce the race condition myself, and that's a lot of work to be honest

Comment: Doesn't the 'BlockingCallbackTransform' solve the issue? If not, please elaborate on what is missing?

Comment: Block transform prevents the use of callbacks with multiple inputs. it changes ctx.triggered_id into a random string and, as a result, makes it impossible to know which input triggered the callback

Comment: I updated my example. You can replace the *code that affects the y axis* with something like time.sleep(3) for the same effect. Right now, that part of the callback never runs because the interval component fires before it finishes

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does what you want. Update data, while keeping layout. You can adapt to exactly what you would like, your example is copied anyhow and not really working (ex: you have a ctx there that is not defined)

The idea of the code below is: rather than update the complete object server side (in the callback) have different "parts" of the object (data-patch1, data-patch2, etc) and "merge" them in the browser (see deep_merge).

Depending on what you want to keep/adjust you can adjust that function and fill accordingly the data-patch.

For the code below you can just zoom in/zoom out, but you could also patch colors, sizes, etc.

```
# From https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/issues/881
import dash
import datetime
import random
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly

figure = go.Figure()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children = [
  html.Div(id="patchstore", 
           **{'data-figure':figure, 'data-patch1':{}, 'data-patch2':{}, 'data-patch3':{}}),
  dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
  dcc.Interval(
              id='interval-component',
              interval=2*1000, # in milliseconds
              n_intervals=0)
])

deep_merge = """
function batchAssign(patches) {
    function recursiveAssign(input, patch){
        var outputR = Object(input);
        for (var key in patch) {
            if(outputR[key] && typeof patch[key] == "object" && key!="data") {
                outputR[key] = recursiveAssign(outputR[key], patch[key])
            }
            else {
                outputR[key] = patch[key];
            }
        }
        return outputR;
    }
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, recursiveAssign, {});
}
"""

app.clientside_callback(
    deep_merge,
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('patchstore', 'data-figure'), 
     Input('patchstore', 'data-patch1'),
     Input('patchstore', 'data-patch2'),
     Input('patchstore', 'data-patch3')]
)



@app.callback(Output('patchstore', 'data-patch1'),[Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def callback_data_generation(n_intervals):
    data = {
        'time': [],
        'Latitude': [],
        'Longitude': [],
        'Altitude': []
    }

    # Collect some data
    for i in range(30):
        time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
        data['Longitude'].append(random.randint(1,10))
        data['Latitude'].append(random.randint(1,10))
        data['Altitude'].append(random.randint(1,10))
        data['time'].append(time)


    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['time'],
        'y': data['Altitude'],
        'name': 'Altitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['Longitude'],
        'y': data['Latitude'],
        'text': data['time'],
        'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)
    if n_intervals==0:
        fig.layout = None
    return fig

app.run_server()
```